# Bookmarklet to open user defined link and make user defined form drop-down box selections

Tags: javascript, automation, macros, bookmarklet, bioinformatics

I've written a bookmarlet to open a user defined web link, in this specific case a specific genomic location in the UCSC genome broswer.

```
javascript:d=%22%22+(window.getSelection?window.getSelection():document.getSelection?document.getSelection():document.selection.createRange().text);d=d.replace(/%5Cr%5Cn%7C%5Cr%7C%5Cn/g,%22%20,%22);if(!d)d=prompt(%22Enter%20the%20chromosomal%20location%20(ex.%20chr1:213243007-213243247):%22,%20%22%22);if(d!=null)location=%22http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?hgS_doOtherUser=submit&hgS_otherUserName=Denilw&hgS_otherUserSessionName=mrkdOvrExpUniqMonometh&position=%22+escape(d).replace(/%20/g,%22+%22);void%200
```

There are 24 chromosomes in the human genome that can be displayed and I would like to do the following:

**1) Parse the chromosome out of the user entered string**

Use a regex in java script to parse 22 from chr22:213243007-213243247 or X from chrX:213243007-213243247

**2) Make selections in the dropdown options of the form on UCSC based on the user input**

There are 4 tracks or data sets to show for each of the 22 chromosomes, 88 in total.  These are available for selection in the *Custom Tracks* section of UCSC genome browser as per the linke chosen above, say

http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?hgS_doOtherUser=submit&hgS_otherUserName=Denilw&hgS_otherUserSessionName=mrkdOvrExpUniqMonometh&position=chr14%3A22%2C409%2C038-22%2C409%2C507

HS0356_chr_*CHROMOSOME*_duplicates_standard_len_triangle
HS0445_dpwg_chr_chr*CHROMOSOME*_duplicates_standard_len_triangle
HS1328_chr_*CHROMOSOME*_duplicates_standard_len_triangle
HS1329_dpwg_chr_chr*CHROMOSOME*_duplicates_standard_len_triangle

Then I would like the drop down menus for the above, where *CHROMOSOME* is defined in part 1 to be changed from *Hide* to *Full* so that only the data for the chromosome of interest will be displayed.

Perhaps something like this would be helpful:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/autoselect.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem,

```
var str = "chr22:213243007-213243247";
var result = /chr(\w*):(\d*)-(\d*)/.exec(str);
if(result)
{
    alert(result[1]) // 22
    alert(result[2]) // 213243007
    alert(result[3]) // 213243247
}
else
{
    // User entered invalid string
    alert("Invalid input");
}
```

If you don't need `result[2]` and `result[3]`, just ignore them.

I looked at the second part of your question (hopefully I understood it right), and most of the drop-downs on the page look like this:

```
<select name="ct_HS1329dpwgchrchr17duplicatesstandardlentriangle_5941" class="hiddenText" style="width: 70px">
    <option selected="">hide</option>
    <option>dense</option>
    <option>full</option>
</select>
```

Now, we can use the following code to get the above `select` element and set the selected option to 'full': (Edit: added a workaround since full element name can't be predicted)

```
// Convert "chr17_duplicates_standard_len_triangle" to "chr17duplicatesstandardlentriangle"
var selectText = "chr17_duplicates_standard_len_triangle";
var selectName = selectText.replace(/_/g, "");

// Find the element that contains "chr17duplicatesstandardlentriangle" in
// it's name.
var selectElements = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for(var i=0;i<selectElements.length;i++)
{
    var ele = selectElements[i];
    var name = ele.name;
    if(name.indexOf(selectName)!==-1)
    {
        ele.selectedIndex = 2;
        break;
    }
}
```

I don't like this solution since it involves looping through all the select elements on the page when you only need one. If someone knows a better solution, please tell me.

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: This is almost perfect, but I don't know how to go from the label of the dropdown menu (written above the dropdown menu, ex. HS1329_dpwg_chr_chr*CHROMOSOME*_duplicates_standard_len_triangle), to the actualy coded name of the dropdown menu (ex. "ct_HS1329dpwgchrchr17duplicatesstandardlentriangle_5941") using javascript.

Comment: I think the problem is the `_5941` at the end of the name. It appears to just be a random number. I'll try to add a work-around in my code.

Comment: Okay, I added the new code, refresh the page to see it. Hopefully it'll work for you.